# possible to index a set by a variable?

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to do something that logically should be possible to do.  However, I am not sure how to do this within the realm of linear programming.  I am using ZMPL/SCIP, but this should be readable to most.

```
set I := {1,2,3,4,5};
param u[I] := <1> 10, <2> 20, <3> 30, <4> 40, <5> 50;

var a;
var b;

subto bval:
  b == 2;

subto works:
  a == u[2];

#subto does_not_work:
#  a == u[b];
```

I am trying to make sure that the variable `a` is equal to the value at the index `b` in `u`.  So for example, I ensure that `b == 2` and then I try to set the constraint that `a == u[b]`, but that does not work.  It complains that I am trying to index with a variable.  I am able to just do `a == u[2]` however, which makes `a` equal to `20`.

Is there a way to easily access `u` at an index specified by a variable?  Thanks for any help/guidance.

---

**EDIT**: I think the consensus is that this is not possible because it no longer becomes an LP.  In that case, can anyone think of another way to write this so that, depending on the value of `b`, I can get an associated value from the set `u`?  This would have to avoid directly indexing it.

---

**SOLUTION**:  Based on the response from Ram, I was able to try it out and found that it was definitely a viable and linear solution.  Thanks, Ram!  Here is sample solution code in ZMPL:

```
set I := {1,2,3,4,5};
param u[I] := <1> 10, <2> 20, <3> 30, <4> 40, <5> 50;

var a;
var b;
var y[I] binary;

subto bval:
  b == 4;

subto only_one:
  sum <i> in I : y[i] == 1;

subto trick:
  b == (sum <i> in I : y[i] * i);

subto aval:
  (sum <i> in I : u[i]*y[i]) == a;
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but no consensus is needed. It's not linear because it doesn't satisfy the definition of linear.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Glad we don't need consensus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite and *linearize* your constraints, by introducing a few extra 0/1 variables (indicator variables). These kinds of tricks are not uncommon in Integer Programming.

**Constraints In English**

`b` can take on values from 1 through 5. b = {1..5}

and depending on b's value, the variable `a` should become `u[b]`

**Indicator Variables**

Let's introduce 5 `Y` variables - Y1..Y5 (one for each possible value of b)

Only one of them can be true at any given time.

```
 Y1 + Y2 + Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 1
 All Y's are binary {0,1}
```

Here's the trick. We introduce one linear constraint to ensure that the corresponding Y variable will take on value 1, only when b is that value.

```
b - 1xY1 - 2xY2 - 3xY3 - 4xY4 - 5xY5 = 0
```

(For example, if b is 3, the constraint above will force Y3 to be 1.)

Now, we want `a` to take on the value u[b].

```
 a = u[1]xY1 + u[2]xY2 + u[3]xY3 + u[4]xY4 + u[5]xY5
```

Since u[ 1] ...u[5] are constants known beforehand, the constraint above is also linear.

Here is [one reference](http://agecon2.tamu.edu/people/faculty/mccarl-bruce/mccspr/new15.pdf) on these kinds of IF-THEN conditions in Integer Programming. Many of these tricks involve the Big-M, though we didn't need it in this case.

Hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: If the question is actually how to "sum across u but cancel out adding to the sum when the index is not 5", adding new variables and constraints is overkill. This answer illustrates a linearization  nicely, but I'm not convinced that it's the right answer for the question.